# Fetch raw transaction data of SafeTransaction

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I am integrating with the @safe-global/safe-core-sdk library. I am wondering how to get the raw transaction data of a SafeTransaction - since one of our signers is a MPC, was wondering if it'd be posssible to generate signature externally and feed that back in via addSignature

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible to get the raw tx data and feed it back into your Safe. Here's a somewhat detailed breakdown of what you need to do.

1. Create a Safe tx(transaction) by calling the `execTransaction` method of the Safe instance and pass in the required params for the tx you want to execute.
2. Fetch the raw tx data by calling the `encodeABI` method of the tx object and pass in the required params. You will get the ABI-encoded data of the tx which you can use to generate the signature.
3. To then generate this signature for the raw tx data you can use an ethereum signing tool such as `ethSign` or a hardware wallet if you own any. The signature will be generated using the private key of one of the owner address of the Safe.
4. Lastly, and the most important part - To feed the signature back into the Safe you can now use the `addSignature` method of your Safe instance to feed the signature back into the contract. As usual once enough signatures have been collected the tx will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the break down!

Comment: You're welcome man. Click on the arrow on my answer up to upvote this if it was useful to you.